# "why" we multiply probabilities (and not add/divide/subtract) when we calculate probability of an event when some other event has happened

Tags: probability

A jar contains 4 black and 3 White balls. If you reach into the jar and pick two balls simultaneously , what is the probability that one is black and the other is white ?

I pick the first black ball in 4/7 ways. This is standard probability stuff (favorable outcomes / total outcomes). Now 6 balls are left. The probability to pick the second ball is 3/6. To calculate probably of picking white ball after black, I multiply 4/7 * 3/6.

Why? Why am I not adding or dividing or subtracting the probabilities?

Comment: Imagine repeating this experiment 700,000 times. In $4/7$ of the trials, the first ball you pick is black. So that's 400,000 trials (approximately) where the first selection is black. In $3/6$ of *those* trials, the second ball you pick is white. So that's 200,000 trials (approximately) where you picked black then white. In other words, in 3/6 of 4/7 of the trials you get the desired outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this visualization will help (think of the *blocks* of favourable outcomes as areas):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \text{B}_1 & \text{B}_2 & \text{B}_3 & \text{B}_4 & \text{W}_1 & \text{W}_2 & \text{W}_3 \\
\hline
\text{B}_1 & \times & & & & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & \bigcirc\\ 
\hline
\text{B}_2& &\times & & & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & \bigcirc\\ 
\hline
\text{B}_3& & &\times & & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & \bigcirc\\ 
\hline
\text{B}_4& & & &\times & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & \bigcirc\\ 
\hline
\text{W}_1 & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & \times\\
\hline
\text{W}_2 & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & & \times\\
\hline
\text{W}_3 & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & \bigcirc & & & \times\\
\hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

LittleO and Andrew Chin have already provided intuitive answers, but if you're looking for a more formal solution, then consider this. For any 2 events $A$ and $B$, we define $\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)$ (the probability of $B$, given that $A$ has occurred) by the equation:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B\mid A) \, .
$$
If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then $\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)=\mathbb{P}(B)$—in other words, knowing that $A$ has occurred doesn't change the odds of $B$ occurring. Hence,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)&=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B\mid A) \\[5pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B) \, .
\end{align}